# Use Hudson Build Parameter in Grails Build Target

Tags: grails, ant, continuous-integration, hudson, gant

I have created two Hudson String Parameters in my parametrized build configuration: `svnRoot`, and `svnBranch`.

I can reference these just fine when specifying my Repository URL: `${svnRoot}/${svnBranch}/subProject`.

But I have not been able to reference them as part of my Grails Build Target: `"build-applet ${svnRoot}/${svnBranch}/appletProject username password" "war --non-interactive"`. `build-applet` invokes a Gant script in the Grails project at `scripts\BuildApplet.groovy`. This attempt yields the following error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
>   No such property: svnRoot for class:
>   Script1   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:240)
>     at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:561)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:536)
>     at
>   com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsBuilder.evalTarget(GrailsBuilder.java:212)
>     at
>   com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsBuilder.perform(GrailsBuilder.java:168)
>     at
>   hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:603)
>     at
>   hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:172)
>     at
>   hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:137)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:417)
>     at
>   hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1337)
>     at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
>     at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>     at
>   hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:140)

What is the best and or easiest way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the wiki page on the Grails plugin (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Grails+Plugin), this should work

```
grails build-applet ${env.svnRoot}/${env.svnBranch}/appletProject username password
```

If not, I'd try a command line build step. Make sure you set GRAILS_HOME as the first line in the script then call grails.

cheers

Lee

Comment: Thank you @leebutts! Your code example didn't quite work but it set me on the right path. First, looking at the documentation you linked, I saw that you forgot to add single quotes around `svnRoot` and `svnBranch` in your example. But even after making that fix, the script choked on `[` when using `System.properties["grails.cli.args"]?.tokenize()` to parse the args. However, using dot notation to dereference the `env` variables worked perfectly: `grails build-applet ${env.svnRoot}/${env.svnBranch}/appletProject username password`. Feel free to update your answer.